# Resources on Andean geology

Tags: geology, mountains, tectonics, paleogeography, reference-request

I would like to begin studying the geology of the Andes, with particular respect to the tectonics and paleogeography of the region.

I have been searching on-line resources for some time and I would like to start reading a book on the topic, but I am not finding any titles focussing on the geology, tectonics and paleogeography of the area. Would anybody have any suggestion, if possible in Spanish?

Since I have found the reference-request tag, I hope this question is not off topic here and, if it is, I will delete it. I thank you for any answer!

Comment: Definitely on-topic. Give the Q some time to get answered.

Answer (score 4):

Some books are about specific parts of the Andes, for example - [The Geology of Chile](http://ebooks.geoscienceworld.org/content/the-geology-of-chile) (Mareno and Gibbons - editors). This book represents a culmination of research in tectonics, geology and such from researchers across Chile.  Given the location of Chile, this is definitely an apt reference.

A comprehensive resource is the book [Tectonic Evolution of South America](http://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?pid=S0716-02082000000200006&script=sci_arttext) (edited by Cordani et al. 2000), this brings together data, information and observations from dozens of scientists across South America.

A paper that is involves a study related to your query is [Andean tectonics as a cause for changing drainage patterns in
Miocene northern South America](http://www.colorado.edu/geolsci/courses/GEOL5700-9/pdf/Spring07/Geol95HoornColombiaAndesDrainage.pdf) (Hoorn et al. 1995) - this looks at the palaeodrainage of the northern portion of South America in the relation to the mountain building and tectonics of the region at that time.

Another paper, is [The proto-Andean margin of Gondwana: an introduction](http://sp.lyellcollection.org/content/142/1/1.full.pdf), this introductory paper reviews the evidence for Andean tectonics and palaeotectonic regimes, stretching back to the Neoproterozoc.

Comment: I thank you very much for your comprehensive list of very interesting resources! I am not checking the answer as accepted, for the moment, only to leave space to attract more suggestion of resources...